# What are these "split thread" screws for?

Tags: screws

I've found a screw like this.
It doesn't have a whole thread, it's threaded both near the tip and near the head but not in the middle.

[image]

What's the purpose of this?

Furthermore the thread is partially serrated, why?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. My guess is that is an extremely specialized screw (especially with the small head and thread-cutting start), and doesn't have anything to do with Home Improvement.

Comment: That looks like a decking screw.

Comment: @DanielGriscom what stackexchange section is good to ask about this?

Comment: This seems like the best place to ask

Comment: I've used screws like that for addressing squeaks in hardware floors....

Answer (score 4):

Doing a quick image search on Google, it looks like Dan D.’s is correct. “That looks like a [decking screw](https://www.homedepot.com/p/FastenMaster-Trio-Ultimate-Deck-Screw-2-1-2-in-75-Piece-FMTRD212-75/203999079).” It is also referred to as a “[terrace screw](https://www.fastenerandfixing.com/construction-fixings/swg-terrace-screws/).”

Comment: This looks even closer, but it certainly looks like a deck screw.  http://www.spaxpacific.com/products/spaxd.html

Comment: OK, but there are no details about the reason of that shape?

Comment: The split thread is so that you can partially reverse the screw (if necessary) to even out flooring levels, i.e. if you have a low spot, then you back out the screw and the board should rise to match. I think there is usually something a little different about the top bit of thread, but maybe not on all examples/

Comment: @MikeBrockington - correct.. but the opposite also works.. once the thread is anchored into the frame base. the split thread enables a separation between the frame base and the board. -- often the "Fixing Thread" -- the section on the top. is slightly more compressed so that the thread ratios differ between the setting thread and the fixing thread -- Essentially presses the board harder onto the frame (preventing creaks)